# Getting Ruby on Rails 3 to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

I just installed RoR 3 with `sudo gem install rails`. I tried this multiple times, but every time I run `$ rails` I get an error and I hate it:

```
imac:~ rsonic$ rails
/Users/rsonic/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin/rails:19:in `load': no such file to load -- rails (LoadError)
    from /Users/rsonic/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin/rails:19
```

How can I fix this? I want to use Rails again!

Comment: try to remove /Users/rsonic/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin/ from your $PATH. If that make it work it means that you have to uninstall rails from your /Users/rsonic/.gem gems

Answer (score 3):

1.Install rvm(Ruby version manager)
    sudo gem install rvm

2.Go to install path of rvm and do
    rvm-install

3.Check if the install was successful by running
    rvm

4.Check for current version of ruby
    ruby -v

5.Install ruby 1.9.2 using rvm
    rvm install 1.9.2

6.User ruby 1.9.2 with the help of rvm do
    rvm 1.9.2
    (you can switch back to system's default ruby version by running command >rvm system)

7.Install gems using rvm do
    rvm gem install tzinfo builder memcache-client rack rack-test rack-mount erubis mail text-format thor bundler i18n
    This will install gems locally for ruby1.9.2 without touchin the sytem ruby

8.Install RAILS3 beta release
    rvm gem install rails --pre

9.Install railties which are required for RAILS3
    rvm gem install  railties --pre

10.For generating a new app with RAILS3 skeleton now do
    rails myapp

*Note all ruby script/* commands have changed to rails *

e.g: RAILS<3
    ruby script/server -p 3004
    RAILS3
    rails server -p 3004

Hope it helps...